# Silverlight button style how to prevent the focused state when the button is pressed?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

In my custom button I need to show that it had  focus(provides some tactile feel to tabbing to the button) and show that its pressed but what I have found  is my focused state is displaying rather then my pressed state.  How can I correct this.  I would like to have mouse over to pressed not mouse over then focused(when the button is clicked )

Here is a sample of my control template.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GavelButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="#FF000000" x:Name="grid">
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FF2844B9"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2000000"/>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.5"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.5"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image Cursor="Hand" x:Name="image" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="11_64x64.png" Stretch="Fill" OpacityMask="#FF000000">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press it is becomes focused, can't do anything about that...you can clear the Visual State Manager's Focus content and then it won't *look* focused, but it get focus from the mouse interaction no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success setting IsTabStop to False. I wouldn't expect it to prevent focus after clicking but that appears to be what it does. After clicking the button, the space bar is not captured.